# I Then Understood

Tags: word-order

Can *then* and *first* be put in the mid-position? I've seen some examples where they are, but I want to know whether they really can be in the most grammatical way.

1. I **then** understood that those small kittens had actually slain all the frogs having dwelt at the swamp.
2. I was **first** amazed by her appearance, but after having learnt what a brazen, merciless person she was, she was forever forgotten by me.

Comment: Adverbial elements like ***then, first, later,...*** can usually be put in various different positions within an utterance. By default, your two examples would normally *start* with ***Then*** and ***At first***, but your versions are "valid". And *sometimes* a competent native speaker / writer might use your positions for effect (and/or discard ***at*** before ***first***) - but since you don't know what that effect might be, you should probably stick to the default positions.